# plesk + high POP3/IMAP traffic, how to check details?

Tags: email, imap, pop3, traffic-filtering

Please check this image, it's a screenshot from plesk 10 of 1 domains mail traffic:

[image]

This domain has about `1GB POP3/IMAP (OUT)` traffic each day. I know that this is not normal because I know the owner and how he's using his mail. It's just some mails each day.

Is `OUT` in this case incomming mails to the domain owner? or is it `OUTgoing` imap traffic?

I have about 30 domains on this machine, but this one is the only one making so much traffic.

How can I check whats happening there? Can I check which email adress makes the most of this traffic? Can I try to swich off Imap for just this domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read this correctly, Plesk shows you the outgoing IMAP traffic. This normally means that an IMAP client connects to your server and checks/receives mails.

This could also be caused by backup or synchronization scripts (I guess you would be aware of those).

My own Plesk installation uses courier-imap with logging disabled at default. I recommend to enable it according to this Plesk Knowledge Base article:
[Enabling POP3/IMAP logging in CourierIMAP.](http://kb.parallels.com/en/6007)

You then should be able to have a look at the logs and find out what is happening there.

Another approach could be running tcpdump or tshark on the IMAP port and look what is happening. The disadvantage of this method is that you would need proper timing.

Comment: thx. one more question: how to disable just IMAP for a single domain? the only way I found until now is to disable IMAP service in firewall for all ...

Comment: Sorry, Plesk seems not to provide a possibility to do that. You'd have to configure that yourself via PAM (see here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/courier-imap-deny-users-573334/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `awk` to parse `/usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog` which is where the Plesk 'statistics' binary pulls it's data from. [This guy](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-36588.html) does something along those lines.